# Flutter difference between = (equal) and : (colon) default parameter initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

I came across this code

```
 const CustomChip({
    Key key,
    this.leading,
    this.trailing,
    this.title,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.height: 30.0,
    this.elevation = 2.0,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

What is the difference between `this.height: 30.0` and `this.height = 30.0` it seems that leaving both undefined makes height 30.0

### Edit

I found something like this too

```
const CustomChip({
    Key key,
    this.leading,
    this.trailing,
    this.title,
    this.backgroundColor,
    double height,
    this.elevation = 2.0,
    this.onTap,
  })
      : height = height ?? 30.0,
        super(key: key);
```

Now I am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use--to-separate-a-named-parameter-from-its-default-value):

> For legacy reasons, Dart allows both : and = as the default value separator for named parameters. For consistency with optional positional parameters, use =.

```
void insert(Object item, {int at = 0}) { ... } // good
void insert(Object item, {int at: 0}) { ... } // bad
```